# Distribution of the maximum of a rescaled Brownian bridge?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion, brownian-bridge

Let $B_t$ denote a standard Brownian bridge, $t \in [0, 1]$.

I am interested in understanding the probability
$$
f(\lambda) = P\Big(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} \frac{|B_t|}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}
> \lambda\Big), \quad \lambda > 0.
$$
My thinking was to rewrite
$$
B_t = \sqrt{\frac{1}{t(1-t)}} \Big(W_t - t W_1 \Big), 
$$
where $(W_t)_{t \in [0, 1]}$ denotes a standard Brownian motion.
Then,
$$
f(\lambda) = P\Big(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} \frac{|W_t|}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}} > \lambda \mid W_1 = 0\Big). 
$$
However, I was struggling to be able to calculate the righthand side above. I was thinking that if
$$
g(\lambda, x) = P\Big(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} \frac{|W_t|}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}} > \lambda, W_1 \leq x\Big)
,$$
Then
$$
f(\lambda) = \frac{\partial_x g(\lambda, 0)}{\phi(0)}, 
$$
where $\phi$ denotes the standard Gaussian density, however, computing $g(\lambda, x)$ seems nontrivial to me.

Comment: This is unlikely to be tractable in the closed form. What do you need it for? One may try to write the asymptotics.